# angular-bootstrap add new directive dosn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I want to create a new directive into ui.boostrap.accordion module to avoid accordion open click event.

I have the following code in another file.js:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.accordion')
.directive('accordionGroupLazyOpen', function() {
  return {
    require: '^accordion',         
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,              
    replace: true,                
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
      return attrs.templateUrl || 'template/accordion/accordion-group.html';
    },
    scope: {
      heading: '@',               
      isOpen: '=?',
      isDisabled: '=?'
    },
    controller: function() {
      this.setHeading = function(element) {
        this.heading = element;
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, accordionCtrl) {
      accordionCtrl.addGroup(scope);

      scope.openClass = attrs.openClass || 'panel-open';
      scope.panelClass = attrs.panelClass;
      scope.$watch('isOpen', function(value) {
        element.toggleClass(scope.openClass, value);
        if (value) {
          accordionCtrl.closeOthers(scope);
        }
      });

      scope.toggleOpen = function($event) {
      };
    }
  };
})
```

The problem is when I execute the app I get the following error:

> Controller 'accordionGroup', required by directive
>   'accordionTransclude', can't be found!

Error [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=accordionGroup&p1=accordionTransclude)

Any ideas?

Comment: does your directive template require a controller 'accordionGroup'? if so, are you defining a controller 'accordionGroup' anywhere?

Comment: I've copied the directive, have changed the name accordionGroup by accordionGroupLazyOpen and have disabled the toggleOpen function for it do nothing. That's the only change it did. Change the name and empty toggleOpen function.

Comment: apparently there are some other directives that require the AccordionGroup and since you renamed it they cannot find it.

Comment: I didn't rename anything, I created another directive and added to the module. I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see from the [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js) ( maybe not your version but still the same):

```
// Use in the accordion-group template to indicate where you want the heading to be transcluded
// You must provide the property on the accordion-group controller that will hold the transcluded element
.directive('uibAccordionTransclude', function() {
  return {
    require: '^uibAccordionGroup',  // <- look at this line in your version
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      scope.$watch(function() { return controller[attrs.uibAccordionTransclude]; }, function(heading) {
        if (heading) {
          element.find('span').html('');
          element.find('span').append(heading);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

So I guess it tries to find a parent directive in the view that matches `accordionGroup` but since you add the `accordionGroupLazyOpen` and not the `accordionGroup` it cannot find it.

In the error page you provided states:

> This error occurs when HTML compiler tries to process a directive that
>   specifies the require option in a directive definition, but the
>   required directive controller **is not present on the current DOM**
>   element (or its ancestor element, if ^ was specified).

If you look in the `accordion-group-template` file you will see that the `accordionTransclude` directive gets called there.

Comment: Good point! I had more problems to adapt the accordion.Finally, everything works well.